# Perl: Why my regex is not matching

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to extract a part of a string using regex. I have the following cases for string:

```
case1: Warehouse.13.season01episode01.hdtv.xor.avi
case2: Warehouse.13.s01e01.hdtv.xor.avi
case3: Warehouse.13.01x01.hdtv.xor.avi
```

The `delimter(.)` in the above string can be replaced by `\s - _`.

The logic am using is check if `s or season` is precided(lookbehind) by number and 
extract everything before it but as look-behind need absolute length I reversed the string
and used look ahead on it.

Now for case1 I created the below regex which works fine and outputs `Warehouse.13`.

```
.*?\d{1,2}e\d{1,2}s\.(?=\d+)(.*)
```

Now for case2 I used:

```
.*?\d{1,2}edosipe\d{1,2}nosaes\.(?=\d+)(.*) # works fine.
```

Now when I try to combine the above two cases + optional delimiter like:

```
.*?\d{1,2}[e|edosipe]?[._ x\-]?\d{1,2}[s|nosaes]?[._\- ]?(?=\d+)(.*)
```

In the above case you can observe that most of the things are optinal(?). It is for the 
case3.

Using the above regex doesn't match anything for case2 but works fine for case1 and case3.

Any idea what is wrong here.

PS: I am aware there might be other possible string which will defy the above regex but 
currently am not interested in them.

Comment: In the examples above, is 'Warehouse' located at the beginning of the string or line?

Comment: @DavidO: Yes filename starts with `Warehouse`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[e|edosipe]` and `[s|nosaes]` should be `(e|edosipe)` and `(s|nosaes)`, or `(?:e|edopise)` and `(?:s|nosaes)` if you don't want the regex engine to capture them and mess up your accounting of `$1`, `$2`, etc.

Here, `(...)` does parenthetical grouping much like it does in any other expression in Perl.
`[...]` defines a character class. Specifically, `[s|nosaes]` matches a single character that is either `a`, `e`, `n`, `o`, `s`, and (perhaps surprisingly, but metacharacters special meanings are usually ignored inside `[...`]), `|`.

Comment: It worked :D. So when I used `[s|nosaes]` it was specifically looking for `n, o, s, a, e, s` and not looking it as a whole world.

Comment: But after making the above changes it is showing no match for case3 :(. My new regex `.*?\d{1,2}(?:e|edosipe)[._\- x]?\d{1,2}(?:s|nosaes)[._\- ]?(?=\d+)(.*)`.

Comment: @ronnie: Previously you were using `[s|nosaes]?` to make that whole group optional so now you can use `(?:s|nosaes)?` to make it optional so that it works for case3.

Comment: @ronnie: Read more [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) about how `?` works.